# Why isn't color burn working on a layer style in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, layer-style, blend-modes

I have a layer with a blending option set to Color Burn and opacity under 91%. It's called Layer 7 is my screenshots.

If I download a jpeg of a solid color of red, and put it behind this layer, the Layer 7's texture is superimposed over it:
[image: texture]

However, when I use a layer that has a color overlay applied, the texture from Layer 7 doesn't show through at all:
[image: no texture]

Why is this and how do I get Layer 7's texture appearing over my color overlay?

Answer (score 5):

This is because the colour overlay's blending mode (or any layer effect's) is a standard `Normal`. It's rather counterintuitive, but that `Normal` does **not** obey the layer's owen blending mode. The overlay you see is therefore a regular red with blending mode `Normal`.

You can fix this by going into the layer effects dialog box and changing the *effect's* blending mode to `Color Burn` as well.

Another option is to check the `Blend Interior Effects as Group` box on the Blending Options: Custom page of the Layer Style dialog. That will make all the styles obey the layer's blending.